# Laravel 8 Migrate Probleme

Tags: php, migration, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

Hi this is my first time using laravel and this is my first try with 'php artisan migrate' command .my DB config is :

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=mysql
 DB_PORT=3306
```

the result that I have is:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor 
  servname provided, or not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where 
  table_schema = pizzahouse and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE 
  TABLE')
```

i tried to change the DB_HOST to local host but I have another problem:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from 
   information_schema.tables where table_schema = pizzahouse and table_name = 
   migrations 
   and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I hope that someone can help me to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: do you use docker?

Comment: no i don't use it

Comment: my guess is:
you have not created a database with the name pizzahouse